# Recebimento HTTP POST Json com PHP MYSQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, http-post

Estou com dificuldades em resolver um problema e conto com a ajuda de vocês. Estou recebendo, de uma API externa, uma requisição HTTP POST no formato JSON com algumas informações. Preciso pegar essa informações separadamente e fazer um UPDATE no MYSQL usando PDO. A API envia as informações no seguinte formato:

```
{"type":"info-type","clientId":"info-client","sku":"info-sku","quantity":info-quantity }
```

Fiz o seguinte para receber e atualizar o banco:

```
<?php

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *);

require('../../config.php');

$json_str = file_get_contents("php://input");
$obj = json_decode($json_str, true);

$sku = "$obj->sku";
$quantity = "$obj->quantity";

print_r($obj);

try {
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOSTNAME . ';port=' . DB_PORT . ';dbname=' . DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE bg_product SET quantity = :quantity WHERE sku = :sku');
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':sku' => $sku,
    ':quantity' => $quantity
    )
);

echo $stmt->rowCount();
}catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'erro no banco de dados';
}

?>
```

Percebi que antes de passar pelo json_decode está assim:

```
"{\"type\":\"info-type\",\"clientId\":\"info-client\",\"sku\":\"info-sku\",\"quantity\":info-quantity}"
```

E depois mostra corretamente:

```
{"type":"info-type","clientId":"info-client","sku":"info-sku","quantity":info-quantity }
```

A mensagem de erro que recebo do PHP é a seguinte: PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object. Bem nessa linhas:

```
$sku = "$obj->sku";
$quantity = "$obj->quantity";
```

Fiz um var_dump e aparece o seguinte:

```
string(99) "{"type":"info-type","clientId":"info-client","sku":"info-sku","quantity":info-quantity}"
```

Parece que não está passando para uma Array corretamente:

Agradeço desde de já.

Answer (score 1):

Para tentar esclarecer o que @rcs respondeu:

Sem o segundo parâmetro **json_decode($json_str)**:

```
$json_str = '{"type":"info-type","clientId":"info-client","sku":"info-sku","quantity":"info-quantity"}';
$obj = json_decode($json_str);

$sku = $obj->sku;
$quantity = $obj->quantity;

print_r($sku);
print_r($quantity);
```

Com o segundo parâmetro **json_decode($json_str, true)**

```
$json_str = '{"type":"info-type","clientId":"info-client","sku":"info-sku","quantity":"info-quantity"}';
$obj = json_decode($json_str, true);

$sku = $obj['sku'];
$quantity = $obj['quantity'];

print_r($sku);
print_r($quantity);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Andre Felipe Azevedo ... Agora deu certo ...

Answer (score 0):

#### O segundo parâmetro para json_decode

O problema é que a função `json_decode` está recendo true como segundo parâmetro, isso faz com que um array seja retornado e não um objeto. Nesse caso, você teria que pegar o valor utilizando `$obj['quantity']`. Ou então mudar o código paraa não passar true como segundo parâmetro da função para poder acessar como objeto com a sintaxe `$obj->quantity`.

Com true como parâmetro um array é retornado, por isso você acessa assim:

```
$quantity = $obj['quantity'];
```

Sem o parâmetro um objeto é retornado, portanto você acessa assim:

```
$quantity = $obj->quantity;
```